# Não consigo obter o último dia do mês. Qual o erro?

Tags: php

Pq esse código não mostra o último dia do mês?

```
    $whiteDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Friday"];
    $year = 2020;
    $month = 4;
    $from = new DateTimeImmutable("$year-$month");
    $to = $from->modify('last day of this month');
    $datePeriod = new DatePeriod($from, DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'), $to);

    $dates = iterator_to_array($datePeriod);

    $filtered = array_filter($dates, function (DateTimeImmutable $day) use ($whiteDays) {

        if (in_array($day->format('l'), $whiteDays)) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Preciso retornar todas as datas codicionadas a vairável  `$whiteDays`. 
Quando executo, tenho uma lista mas nunca aparece o último dia do mês, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

DatePeriod exclui o final do intervalo (no caso, $to). Se quiser incluir o último dia do mês, faça $to igual ao primeiro dia do próximo mês.